# Ответвление проекта

Tags: svn, контроль-версий, tortoise-svn

Был проект версии `1.0`. В него добавили функционал *A* и увеличили версию до `2.0`, а потом добавили функционал *B* и увеличили версию до `3.0`

Сейчас версию `3.0` нужно заморозить, откатиться до версии `1.0`, на основании диффов между `2.0` и `3.0` добавить в проект функционал *B*, зарелизить версию `1.5` и вернуться обратно к `3.0`

Вопрос: как это сделать? Проект регулярно коммитился в SVN. Но в SVN я плаваю. Также установлена Tortoise

Comment: Почти так же как и в Гите, выбрать номер комита и сделать чекоут с этим номером, потом сделать из этого бранч (ветку), и запулить назад сменив номер версии. В двух словах примерно так. Из черепашки кажется сразу можно запилить ветку указав номер ревизии, из чего делать

Answer (score 0):

1. Делайте новую ветку, указывайте из какой ревизии ее сделать и называйте ее соответственно назначению (branch_v1x).
2. Переносите изменения из комитов третьей версии (тут уж смотря насколько версия 3 зависит от версии 2, либо одним диффом все затащить, либо руками все переписывать)